# XML Attributes across schema versions

Tags: xml, xsd

I have following case:

There are two version of a product: Product v1.0 and Product v1.1

v1.0 has schema which successfully verifies following xml:

```
<Root>
  <Tag Name="Tag1">
</Root>
```

v1.1 has schema which successfully verifies following xml:

```
<Root>
  <Tag Name="Tag1" ID="1">
<Root>
```

The new version has a new xml attribute 'ID' and is not possible to successfully validate xml from v1.1 with xml schema from v1.0.
Is there a solution for these kind of scenarios???

Comment: Can you further elaborate on your use case? I suspect the standard solution would be to add `xmlns` attributes to your documents that indicate the URI of the exact schema version each document uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version 1.0 of your XSD is doing its job by failing to validate an XML document that contains an unexpected attribute.

You might have built in some provisions for future updates to your v1.0 XSD using `xsd:any` or `xsd:anyAttribute`.  However, such solutions necessarily defeat the purpose of tightly specifying an interface.  There is an argument against the use of such escape mechanisms that says that flexible but frozen is inferior to precisely evolving, but evaluation of those trade-offs is irrelevant here as you've already made the commitment to an XSD without such escape mechanisms.

Given that you've already committed to a stringently typed interface, you have to face the fact that, left unchanged, your old software/services are dependent upon your old XSD and cannot accept new new XML.

What you might consider doing, however, is making the new attribute be optional (if possible) so that your old XML will continue to be valid against your new XSD.